# cannot frind HKCU\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-registry, cmd.exe

I am trying to permanently change the code page of the cmd.exe. Under HKCU/Console, I can only find the following two keys:

```
%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe
%SystemRoot%_SysWOW64_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe
```

There is nothing about cmd.exe. I guess I can create a key for cmd.exe but just wonder when cmd.exe is launched, from where cmd.exe gets its default values.

Answer (score 0):

If you make any changes to the cmd window while opening it directly (not from a shortcut), these changed settings get saved in `HKCU\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe`